# Updating a Mock object in Java

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock an object using Mockito Library for Java. After mocking the object i am updating some values for that mocked object.

```
Message m = mock(Message.class);
m.put("org.apache.cxf.http.case_insensitive_queries", false);
m.put("org.apache.cxf.endpoint.private", false);
m.put(Message.REQUEST_URI, pathInfo);
m.put(Message.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD, method);
```

However, on debugging the code, i am not able to see the values which i set in the message object.

Attaching screenshot how the message object looks like[image]

Answer (score 0):

The put-method in the mocked message doesn't actually do anything. It only records that it has been called so you can verify the call as part of a test. It's a mock object and not the real thing, after all.